# Python socket always close

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, client

I have a socket client which uses TCP and UDP sockets, even I don't close the socket connection, however, when I finished the execution of the script, the connection is disconnected
How can I keep the connection always ON,
This is the code:

```
import socket
import sys
import time

HOST = "163.173.96.12"  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 32000        # Port to listen on TCP/IP
PORT1 = 32001       # Port to listen on UDP/IP

#TCP/IP
try:
    client_tcp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcp_server_address = (HOST, PORT)
except:
    print("Cannot find server TCP")
finally:
    client_tcp.connect(tcp_server_address)
    print('Connection TCP sucessful')

#UDP/IP
try:
    client_udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 
    udp_server_address = (HOST, PORT1)
except:
    print("Cannot find server UDP")
finally:
    client_udp.connect(udp_server_address)
    print('Connection UDP sucessful')

try:
    for i in range(1,11):
        texte = "PING\n"
        client_tcp.send(texte.encode())
        data=client_tcp.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
        print("Received ", str(data))
except:
    print("error occur")    
finally: 
    #client_tcp.close()
    #client_udp.close()
    print('Closed')
```

Thanks

Comment: What would be the purpose of still being connected after the script finished?

Comment: You can't. Once the process exits, *all* its resources are released. If you don't want that, don't exit.

Comment: Thanks, @user253751 for your question. Actually, this is a script to establish the connection between my app and the server. After that, I have some scripts to execute more. So maybe I must put all scripts into the main program. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @user207421 You mean I have to integrate all scripts into the main program?

Comment: @vapham Right, they all need to be in the same program. I can suggest a tool called Jupyter if you want to be able to edit a program while it stays running.

Comment: @vapham Think about it, even if the same socket stayed open, how would the next script be able to use it?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason I will integrate all of the scripts into functions and put them all together in the main program in which I will define the socket connect at the beginning and disconnect it at the end.

Comment: And I can use the socket as a global variable to use in other functions. Do you think it would be ok?

Comment: @vapham Sure, you can do that. You can also load one script file from another by using `import`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket is closes because when you reach the end of the program the process die then the operating system see resources (socket) that are unused by a process, so it removes them.

To prevent this, you need to prevent the process from dying.
So add one of these at the end of the program, and it will not close, keeping the socket open :

```py
input("Press enter to close")
```

```py
from threading import Event

Event().wait()
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but how can I still keep the connection OPEN even if the execution is finished, because this is just a script to establish the SOCKET connection. After that, my application has to execute other scripts

Comment: It means that you will have to reopen the connection in each script or to open the connection in the parent script and pass it to the child scripts.

Comment: Yes, I think I will convert all scripts into functions, and put them together in the main program in which I will define the socket connect at the beginning and disconnect it at the end. But I don't know how to do it right now, **global socket variable**? do you have any suggestion

Comment: It's possible by using a global variable, my preference would go on having a socket parameter for each function and to pass it (more readable in my opinion) but both solution are perfectly viable.